# Intellij warns forgetting write to 2D array

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After creating a 2D array and filling elements:

```
boolean[][] visited = new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];
for (boolean[] row: visited) {
    Arrays.fill(row, false);
}
```

IntelliJ telling me I did not written into anything into it:

[image]

Why and how to fix it? It's ok when the array is 1D.

Comment: just ignore that warning.

Comment: You are not really writing to it. Well, you are, but only writing over the same initial values. The array values are all initialized to false when you declare it, so by writing false to it you are not really doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will change with this , warning will gone.

```
boolean[][] visited = new boolean[3][5];

for (int i = 0; i < visited.length; i++) {
    Arrays.fill(visited[i],false);
}
```

In your code, there is no row to `foreach` on array. Because of that , it is warning before this.

Comment: Thanks for you time. But it start to complain `for loop` could be replaced by `for each`...

Comment: In your question, warning you to dont foreach on empty array. But in my posted solution , it is saying only alternative way to fill. First one is means "be carefull" , second one is means "change with another usage" in shortly optional way for you.

Comment: And also in first warning you cant correct with alt + enter. But in second one is you can. That is only for alternating way of idea inspectation.